# Web site title showing index of

Tags: html, google-search-console

### Google search jobbulls website title showing index/

I have uploaded all of my files for my website. When I type in my domain name, I see a page titled **"Index of /"** that lists each of the files used to create my website. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Rename the file that you want as your homepage as index.html

Comment: @pepe my homepage file name is index.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming within the scope defined in the [help]


Comment: Also make sure, im not going to append every thought to my answer, that your file is not called index.html.somethingelse when your operating system is obfuscating the file extensions.

Comment: can we see your vhost/.htaccess file? DirectoryIndex might need to be set

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there.

Answer (score 2):

Your first page should be called index.html

In fact, it can be called a lot of names, this is the priority that will decide the one to display: (higher first)

```
index.html
index.shtml
index.php
index.htm
default.html
Default.htm
default.html
Default.html
default.shtml
Default.shtml
page1.html
index.pl
index.cgi
index.php3
index.phtml
home.htm
home.html
home.shtml
index.wml
```

based on the DirectoryIndex by Apache.

Now as a second answer, if you uploaded the files and these contain a file listed above and it still doesn't work, then make sure you uploaded the files in the correct directory. Sometimes ftp brings you one level higher than what is called the 'webroot' check to see if there is no 'public_html' or 'www' or 'html_docs'.
In that case, make sure your files are uploaded in this folders.

Answer (score 2):

It maybe the uploading  folder problem.
First of all you can try these 3 methods,
**Option 1** – Upload Your Website via xxxx's File Manager
**Option 2** – Uploading Your Website via FTP such as FileZilla
**Option 3** – Uploading Your Website via cPanel’s File Manager

Select the option and start to upload.
Open the server folder and you may can see some folders like `.htaccess`, `public_html`.. Please open the folder  `public_html` and upload into it.

If you still see the problem, reupload the files again.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need an index or a page for the web server to serve up as the page for the site.

To get started you could upload an "index.html" page and most web servers will serve this as their first page by default.

Comment: my homepage file name is index.html

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: Filezilla will be the FTP program you are using to upload to the server. Are you able to find out what web server is sending and receiving the web requests? Some common examples are Apache, Microsoft IIS and nginx.

Comment: my web server is Apache

Comment: Do you mind sharing your URL so I can see if I can spot any issues?

Comment: Everything appears to be fine from what I can see. Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Upload this line to your .htaccess file and see what happens

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

If that doesn't work, can you post the contents of your .htaccess file?

This should work for a site coded with php.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution for this you have to set `Options -Indexes` in `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. This was because I used an capital 'I' as first i of `index.html`. This did not work because 'Index.html' was not in my [directory listings](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings). The standard solution for this would be changing `Index.html` to `index.html`. (note the capital 'I' and the lowwer case 'i')

Answer (score -1):

ok first of you have to upload zip file while so It will not give to error while uploading.

put your folder in public_html section extract it.

main page of your file which have to call by default by entering your site name
is **index.html** don't give name Index.html system has access for index.html

Comment: The OP stated in the comments to this six year old question that their homepage was named index.html